# VIM tabs interpreted as spaces instead of tabs

Tags: vim

I switched to a different server at work and I am updating an analysis pipeline. I use vim and after I updated a script and ran it, I got error about inconsistent tabs/spaces. Using `set list` I looked at my code and noticed that using the tab key shows up as spaces regardless of what I did. I have never encountered this issue before.

.vimrc (identical file on both servers)

```
syntax on
set background=light
set tabstop=3
set shiftwidth=3
set softtabstop=3

set hlsearch
set number
set magic
```

Here is a smattering of my original code with some new text written while working on the different server (shown with `set list`).

```
^I^Iif s != sample_list[-1]:$
^I^I^Icombine_list2 = combine_list2 + '\'' + 'S' + count + '\','$
^I^Ielse:$
^I^I^Icombine_list = combine_list + 'S' + count + ')'$
^I^I^Icombine_list2 = combine_list2 + '\'' + 'S' + count + '\')'$
            this is a new line with 3 tabs$
        this is a new line with 2 tabs$
    this is a new line with 1 tab$
 this is a new line with 1 space$
```

I can copy lines from the original code and then overwrite them but that is cumbersome and there are *many* files to update. Assistance getting vim to recognize my Tab keystroke is greatly appreciated.

Comment: See `:help 'expandtab'`.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @romainl -- can you expand on your comment a bit or provide an answer? CTRL-V<Tab> goes to a different terminal window although I am aware that I can do CTRL-V-I.

Comment: You need to `:set noexpandtab`. Issue solved.

Comment: Thanks @Friedrich was able to get tabs appear with `:set noexpandtab` however, this does not work when using `screen` regardless of whether it is in the vrimrc file or set explicitly in vim and therein lies the actual issue. Will do more searching or post new question.

Comment: You didn't mention screen at all in your original question.

Comment: @romainl I did not know screen played a role until I did.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯